# Did anyone ever die during a fantasy in the original run of Fantasy Island?

Tags: fantasy-island

In the episode "Estrogen" of the 1998 revival of *Fantasy Island*, Mary Wilcox is from a military family and, as a woman, is frustrated that she has never been able to fight on the front lines as a soldier like she wanted. Mr. Roarke grants her fantasy by placing her in an alternate World War II in which women are the soldiers, and in the end, she dies saving her comrade.  Mr. Roarke reveals that Mary had terminal cancer, and that her fantasy was really to die as a hero, which she did.

During the original *Fantasy Island* from 1977 to 1984, did anybody die during their fantasy? Or did Mr. Roarke, Tattoo, and the other staff always save them should their fantasy risk becoming lethal?

Answer (score 1):

According to [WikiPedia »](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy_Island) :

It seems that the possibility of death was an accepted outcome for some of the guests' more extreme fantasies, but this was only part of the overall illusion. Something or someone would save them at the last moment.

> Roarke had a strong moral code, but he was always merciful. He usually
>   tried to teach his guests important life lessons through the medium of
>   their fantasies, frequently in a manner that exposes the errors of
>   their ways, and on occasions when the island hosted terminally ill
>   guests he would allow them to live out one last wish. Roarke's
>   fantasies were not without peril, but the greatest danger usually came
>   from the guests themselves. In some cases, people were killed due to
>   their own negligence, aggression or arrogance.

. . .

> With only a few exceptions, Roarke always made it quite clear that he
>   was powerless to stop a fantasy once it had begun and that guests must
>   play them out to their conclusion.

No specific citations about dead guests and a bit of a contradiction later:

> Roarke often preceded particularly risky fantasies with a stern
>   warning, word of caution, or even suggestion that the guest select
>   another fantasy instead. He would then inform his guests that he was
>   powerless to stop a fantasy once it had begun and must allow the
>   fantasy to play out until its ultimate conclusion. Despite this, on
>   rare occasions, Roarke will appear halfway through a fantasy to offer
>   a guest an opportunity to terminate their fantasy, warning the guest
>   that continuing the fantasy may lead to serious consequences (possibly
>   even death). However, at that point, the guest will decide on their
>   own to see the fantasy to its end, either for selfless reasons
>   (regarding someone they had met during the fantasy) or naivety of what
>   is in store for them. In the most serious cases, however, Roarke would
>   invariably intervene and ensure his guests' safety.

A good example of the "guest requests or accepts a deadly outcome but is saved or redeemed" theme works in the episode [Hit Man/The Swimmer »](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0577745/)

> In "Hit Man" a desperate man hires a hit man to eliminate him, so his
>   family can inherit his lucrative insurance money. When suddenly an
>   unexpected sales offer comes to him, is it too late or will Johnny
>   Detroit do him in.

Spoiler alert: the deal works out for him and he narrowly escapes death.

Full episode on YouTube: